# Direction vs sign of bitwise shift/rotation

Tags: function, language-agnostic, arguments, bit-shift

For bit-wise shift (or rotation, circulation) operations, we usually have an **operator**, i mean two of them, for instance

```
x << n
x >> n
```

for **left** or **right** shift of `x` by `n` bits.

We want to define a single **function**

```
bitshift(x, n)
```

Before that, we have to determine, which shift is to be used for **positive** and **negative** `n` - what is the "sign" of each shift (or rotation) direction.

Is there a definition or convention for that?

*(Please note that this question has nothing to do with signed/unsigned types)*

#### UPDATES

*Please also note that i am not asking for implementation details of this function, even it might be somewhat related..*

*There are similar functions in scheme/lisp-like languages, like [ash](http://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/schemexref.cgi?ash), which do left shift for positive `n`*

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for using the sign to indicate direction.

Comment: ScoPi: what i think is that there might be some instances of such functions is some functional languages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since shifting *right* by **k** places is equal to multiplying by **2^-k**, and shifting *left* is equal to multiplying by **2^k**, I think that should give you a hint.

**Note:** Reason I would argue for this way of looking at it is that it is common to consider multiplication as *more fundamental operation* in some sense than division is, although you could certainly argue the other way around.

Comment: i tend to agree.. one can consider it as more-mathematical description of a feeling, that left shift "enlarges" the ``x`` .. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use negative number as argument

For example

x << n

so pass n=2 if yuo want to left shift two positions
and pass n=-2 if you want to right shift two positions.

Comment: nice. unfortunately, that does not apply for any language.. (e.g. Python does not like that)